# clone android project for creating demo version

Tags: eclipse

i have a project and works perfectly, but now i want to create a demo version of it. how i can clone my project and make some limitations in demo version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd encourage you to use a version control system like [git](https://github.com/) and create a branch where you alter functionality of the demo version.